# Can't switch on designMode in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, designmode

The following code works in Firefox 3.6, but not in Internet Explorer 8:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Example</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function init() {
         alert(document.designMode);
         document.designMode = "on";
         alert(document.designMode);
      }
   </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
</body>
</html>
```

In FF the alerts show 'off', then 'on'; in IE they're both 'Off'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though this won't change what the alerts show, it will turn on an editable mode in IE:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Example</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function init() {
         alert(document.designMode);
         document.designMode = "On";
         document.body.contentEditable = 'true';
         alert(document.designMode);
      }
   </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
</body>
</html>
```

You can test by placing some dummy content in the page body (like `<p>Test</p>`) and loading in both FF and IE.  It's a suitable workaround for at least IE8.

Comment: contentEditable does the trick! (And the alerts were just there for debugging anyway.) TVM.

Answer (score 2):

You may have better luck with the [`contentEditable`](http://nagoon97.wordpress.com/2008/04/20/differences-between-designmode-and-contenteditable/) attribute in IE, though `designMode` is the standard.

Answer (score 0):

The Internet Explorer [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533720%28VS.85%29.aspx) seems to indicate that the `designMode` property is case-sensitive, and needs to be set to `"On"`, not `"on"`.

Comment: No, that didn't fix it. Incidentally, if I use a nonsense value like "xx", the assignment throws an exception, so my guess is that "on" and "On" are treated the same.

Comment: Well, it was worth a shot. I'd bet on EAMann's answer being a decent workaround.

Comment: I've actually read that support for the `designMode` property will eventually be dropped in favor of the `contentEditable` method.  Apparently they function somewhat differently and cross-browser support for `contentEditable` is deeper than for `designMode`.  Until the standards gurus make the official call, though, we should probably just develop with both in mind.